# Slidify fails to build example markdown

Tags: r, slidify

I'm on OSX 10.10.3 (Yosemite) running R 3.2.0.

I've just installed slidify following the documentation on its [website](http://ramnathv.github.io/slidify/start.html). In short:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("slidify", "ramnathv")
install_github("slidifyLibraries", "ramnathv")
```

Then load and author a deck in RStudio.

```
library(slidify)
author("mydeck")
slidify("index.Rmd")
```

The last line produces the error:

```
    Error in if (body$content == "") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

And execution halts.

Changing mode or other YAML front matter parameters does not make any difference. Nor adding or removing content. Nor authoring in R command prompt (outside RStudio). I am looking at an indecipherable error message and have no idea where to start looking for its cause. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After some trial and error I see that what causes the error is an inclusion of a list in a slide. Whatever kind of list animated or not will cause the call to slidify  to fail with the above error. I' ve tried a lot of online examples, they all fail with the same error. I even copy-pasted code that works on http://slidify.github.io/playground/ and get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this seems to be an old and known but not already solved problem with the stringr package. 
You have to install an older version of stringr. This worked for me.

install_version("stringr", version="0.6.2")

Here you can follow the discussion:

https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/407